# Using Pinescript to Declare Variables Based on Time Delay (or literal clock time)

Tags: pine-script

Preword -- this is a excerpt from a script by a user who designed the "tradeconnector" browser extension for metatrader and tradingview, so there are codes in the alert messages that are related to that syntax language, but contain dynamic plot variables passed through.

I included an example to give some context to the type of risk management I am coding, namely that this does not require a strategy to execute, it can be either or. I have a counter for trade id, and the ability to partially close a position, dynamic stop loss levels from whichever indicator I ultimately choose, but if you really examin this closely you'll realize it is all predicated on one initial entry alert, i.e, one bid one ticket. I've been having a tough time learning to deal with pyramiding and laddering inside tradingview, and what I specifically want to do is delay the laddering process into a basket of bids based on time delay.

I mentioned the trade id counter, because I thought maybe I could make a counter to keep track of the candle counter to use a sequence of candle counts to make each bid. That was one strategy, and there are of course literal time code an date functions inside pinescript.

But what I really fundamentally need is someway to delcare a new variable every x minutes or seconds, every time a time has passed or to declare a variable/new alert after each delay to get a safer laddering strategy. With a strategy instead of a study, you can turn on pyramiding and have it fire an alert every time you call a strategy.entry, with each line being fed a new variable (based on the new strategy alerts)

Does anyone have any kind of example of how to do something like this in pinescript?
///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
if GoLong 
    stoploss_long := low<pl ? low : pl
if GoShort 
    stoploss_short := high>ph ? high : ph
// } End of Pivot-points and stop-loss logic


  // **** Trade counter and partial closing mechanism **** {
    var int trade_id=0
    if GoLong or GoShort
        trade_id:=trade_id+1



   TakePartialProfitLong = barssince(GoLong)<barssince(GoShort) and crossover(high,(valuewhen(GoLong,close,0)+TakePartialProfitLevel*syminfo.mintick))
   TakePartialProfitShort = barssince(GoLong)>barssince(GoShort) and crossunder(low,(valuewhen(GoShort,close,0)-TakePartialProfitLevel*syminfo.mintick))
    // } End of Trade counter and partial closing mechanism
    


  //strategy.entry("Long", strategy.long, when=GoLong)
  //strategy.exit("XPartLong", from_entry="Long", qty_percent=50, profit=TakePartialProfitLevel)
  //strategy.exit("XLong", from_entry="Long", stop=stoploss_long, profit=TakeProfitLevel)
  //strategy.entry("Short", strategy.short, when=GoShort)
  //strategy.exit("XPartShort", from_entry="Short", qty_percent=50, profit=TakePartialProfitLevel)
  //strategy.exit("XShort", from_entry="Short", stop=stoploss_short, profit=TakeProfitLevel)



  plot_stoploss_long=plot(stoploss_long, title="SLLong", color=na)
  plot_stoploss_short=plot(stoploss_short, title="SLShort", color=na)
  plot_trade_id=plot(trade_id, title="Trade_id", color=na)
  plot_tp_level=plot(TakeProfitLevel, title="TakeProfitLevel", color=na)
    // //defining plots above are required only for the purpose of passing dynamic variables to alerts. Their color is set to 'na' so that they don't display on the screen.

 alertcondition(GoLong, title='Long', message='long slprice={{plot("SLLong")}} tradeid={{plot("Trade_id")}} tp={{plot("TakeProfitLevel")}}')
 alertcondition(GoShort, title='Short', message='short slprice={{plot("SLShort")}} tradeid={{plot("Trade_id")}} tp={{plot("TakeProfitLevel")}}')
 alertcondition(TakePartialProfitLong, title='ClosePartLong', message='closepart tradeid={{plot("Trade_id")}} part=0.5')
 alertcondition(TakePartialProfitShort, title='ClosePartShort', message='closepart tradeid={{plot("Trade_id")}} part=0.5')
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: source -- https://www.tradingview.com/script/9MJO3AgE-TradingView-Alerts-to-MT4-MT5-dynamic-variables-NON-REPAINTING/

Comment: https://kodify.net/tradingview/date-time/bar-time/#get-the-previous-bars-closing-time  I believe it may involve something along these lines , just learned these functions exist. // Calculate the minutes between two bars' closing times
timeDifference = (time_close - time_close[5]) / 60000